# How do I give write permission to file in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

How can I (programmatically) give write permission on a file to a particular user in Linux? Like, for example, its owner? Everyone has read access to this file.

Comment: **This is not off-topic**. This is a specific programming problem. The question is not stellar, but it's not off-topic.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question could be improved, but is *not* off-topic.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In a shell or shell script simply use:

```
chmod u+w <filename>
```

This only modifies the write bit for the user, all other flags remain untouched.

If you want to do it in a C program, you need to use:

```
int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode);
```

First query the existing mode via

```
int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
```

... and just set the write bit by doing `newMode = oldMode | S_IWUSR`. See `man 2 chmod` and `man 2 stat` for details.

Comment: If you are setting it, you can skip querying the current one and ORing the mode, and directly use `chmod(path, 0666);`.

Comment: @Delan Azabani: The poster said: *"give write permission of a file to a particular user"*. Your code would give *everyone* write access which is probably not what the poster wanted. If you want to preserve the access modes for group and other you must query the current mode and OR with the desired flag.

Comment: Gah, I made a mistake, sorry. Sorry, I meant `chmod(path, 0644);`, which should do what is expected. I interpreted the *"But, which can be accessed and read by any other user."* part as a green light to resetting the group and other modes.

Answer (score 13):

The octal mode `644` will give the owner read and write permissions, and just read permissions for the rest of the group, as well as other users.

```
read     = 4
write    = 2
execute  = 1
owner    = read | write = 6
group    = read         = 4
other    = read         = 4
```

The basic syntax of the command to set the mode is

```
chmod 644 [file name]
```

In C, that would be

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

chmod("[file name]", 0644);
```

Comment: The problem here is that you're also modifying the flags for group and others. That may or may not be what the poster wants, it isn't exactly clear from his question. But in your C example you're using mode 0666 instead of the 0644 you've proposed earlier. That would give *everyone* write access which most likely is not what the poster wanted.

Comment: Again, sorry, I made a mistake there; fixed. I interpreted the *"But, which can be accessed and read by any other user."* part as a green light to resetting the group and other modes.

Comment: @Delan Azabani: Yes, you might be right here, I've overlooked that part. The question really should have been more specific...

Answer (score 2):

```
chmod 644 FILENAME
```

6 is read and write, 4 is read only.  Assuming the owner of the file is the user you wish to grant write access to.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that using chmod, on ubuntu you can try out
$sudo chmod 666 
This would give read/write permissions to all...check this out for more details:
http://catcode.com/teachmod/

Comment: Except that's not what the asker wanted.

Answer (score -1):

in shell script, if you want to grant access to the user "john" and they belong to the group "users," you would run:

sudo chown john:users example.txt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But this question is tagged `c`, so a shell answer isn't particularly helpful.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `chmod 777 <filename>`

Comment: That looks like shell, not C, and it gives more than just write permission to a specific user, so not very good advice at all.